# HTML string handling in JSP

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, iframe

I get some HTML from an outside application through an API, and I have it in a JSP variable.
Now the problem is they have a separate set of stylesheets and our application has a different style.
When I embed their HTML in a `div`, my whole application UI collapses.
So I tried to create an iFrame and placed it inside, but it still did not work.
So I assigned it to a variable and created a javascript Blob and attached that as an `src` for the iFrame. This worked fine.

Now the problem is, the variable that I have assigned contains this HTML, and I have kept it has an input `hidden`.

```
<input type="hidden" name="outsideHTML" id="outsideHTML" value='${htmlContent}'/>
```

The incoming HTML has its own `DIV` and styles. The nonhidden elements are displayed on our page, even though the input element type is `hidden`.
So I changed it and added a `div` around it and assigned `inherit` visibility for the input. But it still, it displays the input `hidden` content.

```
<div style="display: none;"><input type="hidden" name="outsideHTML" id="outsideHTML" value='${htmlContent}' style="visibility: inherit;"/></div>
```

Below is my IFrame:

```
            <iframe id="htmlReportFrame" onload="resizeIframe(this)" scrolling="no"  style="overflow:hidden; min-width:985px; min-height:827px; border:0;"></iframe>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myPage = $('#outsideHTML').val();                       
    var blob = new Blob([myPage], {type: "text/html"});
    var blob_url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    var blob_iframe = document.getElementById('htmlReportFrame');
    blob_iframe.src = blob_url;

    function resizeIframe(iframe) {
        iframe.height = iframe.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + "px";
        window.requestAnimationFrame(() => resizeIframe(iframe));
      }

</script>
```

Can anyone throw some light on how to solve this issue?
If using IFrame for this problem is not a solution can you suggest some options?
**I have no handle or control on the incoming HTML.**

Comment: Since I did not find a solution for this, I have solved it creating separate pages for each of the reports

Answer (score 0):

I think if you remove `style="visibility: inherit;`, it should work. Check the below sample and run.

```html
<div style="display: none;"><input type="text" name="outsideHTML" id="outsideHTML" value='${htmlContent}'/></div>
```

Comment: Hi Siva, I problem is the content in the HTML has div and other HTML elements that are supposed to be hidden since it is in the input hidden element. But those are displayed. I have edited the question.